# Unknown column 'userprofile.id' in 'field list

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, django-views

I ma getting this error while calling save method. the error is Unknown column 'userprofile.id' in 'field list

```
class Userprofile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    profile_id = models.IntegerField(db_column='profile_id')  # Field namemade lowercase.
    f_name = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    l_name = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    dob = models.DateField(db_column='DOB', blank=True, null=True)  # Field namemade lowercase.
    contact_number = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    joining_date = models.DateField(db_column='Joining_date', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    temp_address = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    permanant_add = models.CharField(db_column='Permanant_add', max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    user_image = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    gender_idgender = models.ForeignKey(Gender, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='gender_idgender')

    class Meta:
         managed = False
         db_table = 'userprofile'
         unique_together = (('profile_id', 'gender_idgender'),)
```

This is my model

Comment: Add your views and full stacktrace of the error.

Answer (score 0):

“_id” is suffix syntax in django query,You'd better not use it as a field name in your model。